# How to disable Strong Passwords on Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We are in the process of moving a database from on-premise into Azure SQL. The software that will consume this database has a database username and password hard coded, so we are unable to change it. Unfortunately the hard coded password does not meet the password policy for Azure SQL.

I have looked around and found the `CHECK_POICY` option I can add to the query, however I receive an error telling me that option is not supported in this version of SQL.

`Keyword or statement option 'check_policy' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.`

I am also unable to find any documentation that specifically says "You cannot change the password policy in Azure SQL" - Does anyone know how I can either disable the password policy, or find documentation stating that we are unable to do so?

Comment: This is a good thing you can't disable the password policy. It is by design and for good reason. These databases are available on the internet, weak passwords would be criminal in this environment.

Comment: off-topic - belongs on dba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure sql database doesn't support `CHECK_POICY`. So you could not  `set CHECK_POLICY = ON or OFF`.

For more details, please see: [Syntax for Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#syntax-1):

```
ALTER LOGIN login_name
  {
      <status_option>
    | WITH <set_option> [ ,.. .n ]
  }
[;]

<status_option> ::=
    ENABLE | DISABLE

<set_option> ::=
    PASSWORD ='password'
    [
      OLD_PASSWORD ='oldpassword'
    ]
    | NAME = login_name
```

Only local SQL server and Azure SQL managed instance support set `CHECK_POLICY`.

You also can get this from [Password Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017#policy-enforcement).
[image]

> SQL Database enforces password complexity. The password expiration and policy enforcement sections do not apply to SQL Database.

Hope this helps.